# Downloads on Vista Home Premium start off fast but slow down to 0 Kb/s and hang

Tags: windows-vista, download, performance

I have Windows Vista Home Premium on my computer and everytime I go to download something, it starts out at about 1.5 Mb/s and stays there for about 3 seconds, then it slows down to 800 Kb/s and continues to drop until it gets down to 0 Kb/s and hangs. I've tried just about everything I can find such as uninstalling all firewalls/antivirus, doing the netsh rss,autotune, and chimney disable, and updating everything but it still continues to happen. I'd prefer not to reinstall but if I have to then I have to...

EDIT: Figured it out, the router needed a firmware update

Comment: Please add your edit to an answer, and then accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the router needed a firmware update